# Why is it faster to select and copy 58000 rows than to delete 10000

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

An MS Access 2010 Table contains 68,000 rows and roughly 10,000 of them are duplicates. Deleting all 10,000 with the following query takes almost 8 hours:

```
DELETE * FROM [DATA]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT MAXID FROM (
        SELECT MAX(ID) AS MAXID
        FROM [DATA]
        GROUP BY ID_TIME, CURRENCY, ....
    )
    WHERE ID = MAXID
)
```

Change `DELETE` to `SELECT` and it still takes 10 minutes. However, if I remove `NOT`, the query takes about a second to finish, even though the amount of returned rows increases by 48,000:

```
SELECT * FROM [DATA]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT MAXID FROM (
        SELECT MAX(ID) AS MAXID
        FROM [DATA]
        GROUP BY ID_TIME, CURRENCY, ....
    )
    WHERE ID = MAXID
)
```

Copying all 58,000 rows to a temporary table, completely deleting every entry in the original table, copying everything back to the original and then deleting everything in the temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO DATA_TEMPORARY_CLEANUP_TABLE
SELECT * FROM [DATA]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT MAXID FROM (
        SELECT MAX(ID) AS MAXID
        FROM [DATA]
        GROUP BY ID_TIME, CURRENCY, ....
    )
    WHERE ID = MAXID
);

DELETE * FROM [DATA];

INSERT INTO [DATA]
SELECT * FROM DATA_TEMPORARY_CLEANUP_TABLE;

DELETE * FROM [DATA_TEMPORARY_CLEANUP_TABLE];
```

Takes 30 seconds at most. Why?

(1) Why is `NOT EXISTS` so much slower than `EXITS`?
(2) Why is deleting 10,000 rows almost 1,000 times slower than copying 116,000 and deleting 126,000 rows?

Comment: Mostly because of indexes management and space allocation on HDD

Comment: Your question is too broad.  The `delete` has to log all its transactions, so it is generally relatively slow.  As for `exists`/`not exists` . . . those depend on the optimizer.  Plus there might be a better way to write the query.